# SVG to Java Graphics2D

Tags: java, graphics, svg, graphics2d

Can anyone suggest some good way to generate Graphics2D object form SVG data?

I've seen Apache Batic lib, but it seams that they use some JSVGCanvas that gets the URI etc… And I want a Graphics2D stuff instead of JComponent.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: I googled for this and the first promising thing that came up was [JViews](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/integration/visualization/java/). Is that along the right lines? I don't want to post as an answer since I have no clue about Graphics2D, but most of the SVG standard is inline or dumbed down from standard vector concepts, other than CSS, so I imagine a converter exists.

Comment: @Anthony I don't get yet how JViews can help me. Bu the idea is like this. My app lets user to add custom elements. Element has it's graphical representation (in Graphics2D, standard Java vector stuff). I want to give user an option to add elements picture in easy way. I've chosen SVG format as it's super easy to create it using some free stuff, even online generators. Now I want to find a solution how to draw a data from it in graphics 2d.

Comment: The main link wasn't very informative, but when I google for it, tons of stuff came up. Look at this one, fors starters: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/jviewmap/v8r7/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.ilog.jviews.defense.doc%2Fjviews-framework87%2Fsamples%2Fsvg%2Findex.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to look at [SVG Salamander](http://svgsalamander.java.net/) library. On [this page](http://svgsalamander.java.net/docs/use.html) there are some starting tips. It's a good thing if You want only to draw some svgs.