# Draw SVG images on a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, svg

I want to draw SVG images, scaled, rotated, coloured and with an alpha layer onto a JPanel in my Java application. How can I achieve this? There may be multiple of these images overlapping.

I don't really know how to use SVG images in Java so please explain from the start, not only the rendering process :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried Googling it before coming here?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9939727/svg-to-java-graphics2d

Comment: @JoshM Yes I have actually, but I never got the same question as this..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use Batik (http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/) or SVGSalamander (https://svgsalamander.java.net/).  I've used batik successfully before but I have not tried SVGSalamander.

In batik, there is an SVG panel that will display the image for you and add keyboard/mouse shortcuts for zooming, panning, and rotating the image.  You can disable these shortcuts and implement your own mechanisms, however.

Also, with some work you can overlap the images.

Just be sure to read the FAQs.

Comment: Thanks! If I need help with this, I'll just post another question :)

Comment: No problem.  SVG can get complex if you are manipulating them or making them interactive, but just displaying them should be simple.  Both links have examples.

Answer (score 13):

You need to get the SVG image into a type that can be displayed by the JPanel -- I'm going to assume you already know how to use `BufferedImage` to display e.g. a PNG, and that you don't need to edit the SVG, just display it.

The key here is that Java doesn't have native support for SVG. You have to use a library like [batik](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/) to load and convert the image to a displayable format.

I stole this answer from http://bbgen.net/blog/2011/06/java-svg-to-bufferedimage/

**Write a simple Transcoder**

```
class BufferedImageTranscoder extends ImageTranscoder
{
  @Override
  public BufferedImage createImage(int w, int h)
  {
    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    return bi;
  }

  @Override
  public void writeImage(BufferedImage img, TranscoderOutput output)
  {
    this.img = img;
  }

  public BufferedImage getBufferedImage()
  {
    return img;
  }
  private BufferedImage img = null;
}
```

**Using the Transcoder**

```
public static BufferedImage loadImage(File svgFile, float width, float height)
  {
    BufferedImageTranscoder imageTranscoder = new BufferedImageTranscoder();

    imageTranscoder.addTranscodingHint(PNGTranscoder.KEY_WIDTH, width);
    imageTranscoder.addTranscodingHint(PNGTranscoder.KEY_HEIGHT, height);

    TranscoderInput input = new TranscoderInput(svgFile);
    imageTranscoder.transcode(input, null);

    return imageTranscoder.getBufferedImage();
  }
```

Then, just display the rendered `BufferedImage` on your JPanel as if it were a PNG or whatever.

Comment: This defeats the purpose of using SVG graphics.  You lose the smooth scaling of the image.

Comment: That depends on your use case ... i.e. if scaling is an application requirement.

Comment: Also, with work you can intercept the messages that would cause zooming and do the necessary transformation.

Comment: That would be slow.  Plus, if you are using large, detailed images an SVG Document is going to consume less memory than a BufferedImage.  If all you need is a BufferedImage without scaling then just convert the images to PNG or JPEG and call it a day.

Comment: I'm using simple SVG images, at most one image will be changed at a time, but mostly they are stationary.

Comment: @PaulProgrammer I'm having the same issue, wanted to rasterized an svg that contains an image(already rasterized), and throws exception that it can't be rasterized . Any ideas to solve this?